# MDX query for Nth,N+1th records from top

Tags: mdx

I want to build a MDX query for getting 6th to 10th record from the top from the result set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Subset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144767):

```
Subset('your set', 5, 5)
```